# Meaning of まで in 地下３階まであります

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension, particle-まで

> 東京都多摩市で２６日午後２時ごろ、つくっているビルが火事になって、５人が亡くなりました。ビルは３階建てで、**地下３階まであります**。
>   Around 2 o'clock on the afternoon of the 26th in 多摩市 5 people died when a building which was under construction caught fire. It's a three storey building *and has as many as three basement levels*.

I'm not convinced by my translation of 地下３階まであります.
1) I would have expected to see が after 地下.
2) What does まで mean here? My guess is that it means 'as many as', suggesting that three basement levels is a surprisingly large number.
3) If my translation is correct then do you not count underground floors when you state how many storeys a building has (3 above ground + 3 under ground = a 6 storey building)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「ビルは３階建{がいだ}てで、地下{ちか}３階{がい}まであります。」

You translated that to:

> "It's a three storey building and has ***as many as*** three basement levels."

Though it conveys all of the essential information expressed by the original, "as many as" might not be the best translation.  I will come back to this in a second.

> 1) I would have expected to see が after 地下.

That would have still be grammatical and fairly natural.  If anything, however, it would have sounded just a tiny bit informal for news writing, which is a fairly "formal" type of writing.  You would want to avoid sounding wordy even if it were by just one syllable.

> 2) What does まで mean here? My guess is that it means 'as many as', suggesting that three basement levels is a surprisingly large number.

It means "***up to***" here.  You seem to be thinking of another usage of 「まで」.  No surprise implied here as it is not like the building has 20 floors in the basement while having only 3 above the ground.

> 3) If my translation is correct then do you not count underground floors when you state how many storeys a building has (3 above ground + 3 under ground = a 6 storey building)?

That is correct.  You only count what stands above the ground in saying 「N階建{かいだ}てのビル」.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my English brain I read 'up to' and 'as many as' with quite similar meanings in this context. It sounds like either the reporter isn't sure about how many floors there are, or is suggesting that the number is slightly unexpected. I guess when **you** say 'up to' here you mean it as marking the end point of counting from one to three. Which leads me to ask whether まで is needed at all. How is the nuance changed if I omit this particle?

Comment: まで obviously means that there are 地下１階 and ２階 too, while 地下３階がある doesn't refer to it.

Comment: @user4092 Are you suggesting that 地下３階があ means 'there is a floor number 3' rather than 'there are 3 floors'? If not, then I don't understand your comment. I thought it meant ' there are 3 floors'.